# how to give the same table two different column values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

i want to create a database containing 2 principals tables product and provider, but the thing is, sometimes the same product have different prices depends on the provider, i think i should create a new table between the two and put the price in it, will this work ? thank you

Comment: I downvoted because "yes or no?"

Comment: `mysql` **and** `sql-server`, sure...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a join table with one foreign key referencing the product and another referencing the provider.  Add a third column for the price.

Comment: You also might want to add a unique constraint for the product and provider combination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work, is the short answer

Comment: Shouldn't "yes or no?" questions just be closed?

Comment: This answer is in the LQP queue, btw.

Comment: @EJoshuaS [How should you respond to a “Yes or No” question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337245/how-should-you-respond-to-a-yes-or-no-question) (And others)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Surely "Will this work?" questions are better than "Here is my problem. Give me the codes" questions?

Comment: @podiluska Yeah, I guess they're "better," but more in the sense of "less bad."

Answer (score 0):

obviously it will work, as products can have different providers, as well as there are different providers for the same single product, the relation becomes many-to-many, define a new table between the, it may help you out.